# .net MSMQ desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, communication, msmq, messaging

I am trying to learn MSMQ and I started by doing two simple console applications. A transmitter, and a receiver.

To begin with, this is the transmitter code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageQueue.Exists(path))
                {
                    mqueue = new MessageQueue(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    mqueue = MessageQueue.Create(path);
                }
                Timer timer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, 3000, 3000);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            }


        }

    static void timerCallback(object state)
    {
        Student student = new Student(randomString(), randomString(), randomString());
        mqueue.Send(student);
        System.Console.WriteLine("sent: {0}", student.ToString());
    }
```

And the receiver:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageQueue.Exists(path))
                {
                    mqueue = new MessageQueue(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    mqueue = MessageQueue.Create(path);
                }
                Type [] supportedTypes = {typeof(Student)};
                mqueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(supportedTypes);
                mqueue.BeginReceive(new TimeSpan(0,0,5000), mqueue, new AsyncCallback(messageReceived));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

The app works perfectly but I would like to change the communication channel to `TcpChannel/ HttpChannel`. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeProject: creating a WCF service with MSMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and) gives you a nice tutorial about msmq. Some searching makes me conclude that this is only possible in wcf but I can be wrong.